# How can I avoid warnings about security in input fields on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, https

After the last Firefox updates, I'm receiving a message about the security of non-https websites direct in the input fields. The below image shows the message in Portuguese, but it's something like: "This connection is not secure. The accounts used here may be compromised."

[image: input in Firefox with message in Portuguese]

The message appears even on the sites where I have saved login/passwords ("JAMESM" in my example).

This message is a good improvement for Firefox in my opinion, but I trust in some sites and in these cases the message can be annoying. So I want to know if I have any option to avoid this message in a exceptions' list or something.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new enhanced security feature in Firefox 51.0 and based upon the article linked within their [change log](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/51.0/releasenotes/), there doesn't appear to be any type of opt-out or exception list:

[image: Firefox Warning]

(Source:  [Insecure Password Warning in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/insecure-password-warning-firefox))

Comment: I hope they create a list of exceptions in the future. Thanks for your answer anyway, I tried the firefox support site but didn't found this page.